# Creating a hyperlink in active cell from uploaded file

Tags: hyperlink, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm designing a shared Google Sheets for our team to keep track of each piece of content we produce. I want to implement a feature that allows people to upload a preview clip and have a hyperlink automatically created within the active cell.

My script so far serves up HTML as a user interface with a file upload and name entry. This part works fine and allows anyone to upload straight to Google Drive.

I've been having trouble getting it to automatically create a hyperlink in the active cell to the uploaded file. Been searching around, but haven't had a great deal of luck.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('File Upload')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload A File');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Clips";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  }  catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to modify the return value from `uploadFiles()` to be an object, then use the URL to populate a spreadsheet `HYPERLINK()` formula.

```js
return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();
```

Becomes:

```js
return {
  result: "File uploaded successfully",
  fileURL: file.getUrl(),
  fileDesc: file.getDescription()      // Could be other values
};
```

Next, a function that sets the formula. This server-side function would be called with the values to be used in the formula, which were previously returned from `uploadFiles()`. I'm assuming this is from your client-side JavaScript, but that's just a guess, since you didn't include that in your question.

```js
function setHyperlink( fileURL, fileDesc ) {
  var formula = '=HYPERLINK("' + fileURL + '","' + fileDesc + '")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveCell()
                .setFormula( formula );
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had a play around with this, but unfortunately couldn't get it working. However, it did get me thinking about the problem differently - so thanks for that!

I ended up using the GAS Properties Service to handle passing URL and name data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue using the GAS Properties Service - creating 2 new User Properties to contain URL and Name data.

I also found a few issues with getActiveCell - it kept placing the link in A1. Although I had used Google's suggested method for returning the active cell, I was able to use the fix suggested here:
http://bit.ly/20Gc7l6

Here's my final script

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('File Upload')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload A File');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Blacksand Clips";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription(file.getDescription());

    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var link = file.getUrl();
    var name = file.getName();
    userProperties.setProperty('link', link);
    userProperties.setProperty('name', name);
    setHyperlink();

    return "File uploaded successfully ";

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }
}

function setHyperlink() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var link = userProperties.getProperty('link');
  var displayName = userProperties.getProperty('name');

  var value = 'hyperlink("' + link + '","' + displayName + '")'
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().activate();
  cell.setFormula( value )

  return true;
}
```